# Can I include the ADB command line tool inside the bundle of my MacOS app?

Tags: android, macos, adb

I would need to include ADB command line tool inside the bundle of my MacOS Cocoa app. 
I've two questions:

1. Is this an infringement of Google/Android ADB copyright?
2. There are technical drawbacks/problems addressing ADB calls inside the bundle?

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same problem right now. Did you find any meaningful information about either of the question you ask ?

Comment: Unfortunately until now, no